lvm2: Move a live copy, leaving a snapshot behind?
Assume I have a LVM2 VG on two PVs, sda and sdb. A large LV currently is on sda.
I now want to create a snapshot and migrate the LV to sdb. The desired end state is that the live copy is on sdb and the (dense) snapshot remains on sda. (I want to then split the volume group and move sda to an off-site vault for archival storage.)
Is there a way to do this? If so, how?
One idea I came up with is to lvconvert --type raid1 -m1 /dev/sdb , then do lvconvert --splitmirrors 1 --name LV_archive /dev/PV/LV /dev/sda; the problem with this solution is that the system still writes to sda while the mirror is built. I want to avoid that if possible.
